# Bayesian Estimation Derivation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayesian, estimation

I am trying to understand Bayesian estimation and I come across this line in my lecture notes:

```
 θ(Bayesian) = E_θ|x[θ] =  E[π(θ|x)]
```

So it's meant to reader that the Bayesian estimator is the Conditional Expectation of the sample (x's) which equals the expectation of the posterior (3'rd expression). I understand the derivation up to this point but I dont see how the conditional expectation of theta:

So the middle expression "E_θ|x[θ]" (should look like E underscore θ|x of θ) is:

Integral [θ · π(θ|x) dθ]

and somehow that equals the expectation of the Posterior i.e.

```
E[π(θ|x)]
```

Please help! I am hoping it is a simple answer cause there is no explanation between these steps.

Comment: I've tried thinking about it as   E_Y|X (y) =  E [ f_Y|X (y|x) ]  if that helps but I haven't been able to find a solution, probably because I don't know how to deal with the RHS expectation of a conditional density....

Comment: I guess its a matter of notation. Let $\pi(\theta |x)$ be the posterior, then the posterior mean (which is the Bayesian estimator), denoted as $\mathbb{E}[\pi(\theta |x)]$, is given by
$$\int \theta \ \pi(\theta | x)d\theta.$$
The above is simply the conditional expectation of $\theta$ w.r.t the observations $x$ and this is exactly the posterior mean.

Comment: I get that the expression you wrote out is the conditional expectation, thats what a bunch of the derivation leads up to. But how does that equal to the Expectation of  the posterior. I mean thats what we are trying to prove isnt it? It seems to me like you are using the result of the proof in the proof.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @MauroAugusto: because $\pi(\theta|x)$ is the posterior density which is a function of $\theta$. Therefore, the integral is exactly the definition of the mean of the posterior (.... recall the definition of the expected value of a random variable).

Comment: I've always thought the definition expected value was E[g(X)] = ∫g(x) f_X(x) dx. If g[X] =π(θ|x) I don't see how its simply just ∫θ π(θ|x)dθ. Where did θ come from? Is it somehow the density of π(θ|x)?

Comment: No wait I think I'm seeing my disconnect... so is E[X] the same as E[f_X(x)]  where f_X(x) is the density of X. Cause if so I think I get it.

Comment: I have not read many Bayesian materials, and not sure if there is such a convention to write the expectation like this. From my understanding, I will write the posterior mean as $E[\Theta|X]$, and I will not put the (conditional) density inside like that. It is confusing and awkward to me.

Comment: Like I said, its just a matter of notation ... which makes it confusing in this case. There are various notations that are used. You do not need to interpret $\mathbb{E}[\pi(\theta | x )]$ literally. Instead, you should know that $\pi(\theta | x)$ is the posterior density and the mean posterior is then given by
$$\int \theta \pi(\theta \ | \ x)d\theta,$$
by definition!

Answer (score 3):

At the begin, you should make sure what is the Bayesian estimator. In chapter 11 of [1], Bayesian estimator is defined as an estimator which minimizes the Bayesian mean square error (Bayesian MSE). Let $\boldsymbol{x}$ be an observed signal, $\theta$ is estimated signal and $\hat{\theta}$ is estimator of $\theta$. With those knowledge, we have 
\begin{align}
\text{Bmse}\  (\hat{\theta})
&=\int (\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2p(\boldsymbol{x},\theta)\text{d}\boldsymbol{x}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\int \left[{\int (\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2p(\boldsymbol{x}|\theta)\text{d}x}\right]p(\theta)\text{d}\theta
\end{align}
Thanks to the non-negativity of $p(\theta)$, the minimum of Bayesian MSE can be touched via minimizing inner integral. To this end, we take partial derivative of inner integral w.r.t $\hat{\theta}$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{\theta}}\int (\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2p(\boldsymbol{x}|\theta)\text{d}\boldsymbol{x}=-2\int \theta p(\theta|\boldsymbol{x})\text{d}\theta+2\hat{\theta}\int p(\theta|\boldsymbol{x})\text{d}\theta
\end{align}
Let it be 0 yields 
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}=\int \theta p(\theta|\boldsymbol{x})\text{d}\boldsymbol{x}=\mathbb{E}\left[{\theta|\boldsymbol{x}}\right]
\end{align}
In signal process domain, $p(\theta|\boldsymbol{x})$ is called as posterior distribution.

References

[1] Sengijpta S K. Fundamentals of statistical signal processing: Estimation theory[J]. 1995.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to take into account that Bayesian Inference derives itself from decision theory.

Second, in Bayesian inference the point estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is the value that minimizes the *Expected Loss Function*.

So, for instance, let $\pi(\theta | X_{(n)})$ be the *posterior distribution* of $\theta$ given the sample $X_{(n)}$ and $\mathcal{L}(\theta, \hat{\theta})$ the **Loss function**.

So given this two definitions $\hat{\theta}$ will be the value tha minimizes the **Expected Loss** given by $$\int_{\Theta} \mathcal{L}(\theta, \hat{\theta}) \pi(\theta | X_{(n)})d\theta =\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[L(\theta, \hat{\theta})|X_{(n)}]$$.

Solving this integral for different loss functions yields **different point estimators** for $\hat{\theta}$, i.e.

- $\mathcal{L}= (\theta - \hat{\theta})^2$ yields the *expected value*/*mean* of the posterior distribution $\pi$, i.e. $E_{\theta}[\theta|X_{(n)}]$ which is the **BMSE** in the answer above.
- $\mathcal{L}= |\theta - \hat{\theta}|$ yields the *median* of the posterior distribution $\pi$.
- $\mathcal{L}= \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
  1 & \mbox{for}
  & |\theta - \hat{\theta}|<\varepsilon \\ 0 & \mbox{for} & |\theta - \hat{\theta}|>\varepsilon
  \end{array}\right.$ yields the *mode* of the posterior posterior $\pi$.

However you can construct any loss function that correctly represents preference in your particular *inference decision problem*.

I really recommend to you looking at this [introductory course in bayesian statistics](http://allman.rhon.itam.mx/~lnieto/index_archivos/NotasBayesMR.pdf) by Manuel Mendoza to get some real graps on bayesian theory and the axioms underlying Bayesian Inference.